# AOS just work with first element (Angular)

Tags: angular, animation, scroll, aos.js

Animation for few elements works fine, but not for all. I tried and inspect issue in browsers developer tool and found that "aos-animate" class does not get applied to those elements.

Any Guess why it is happening?

More inputs

- I have  ngOnInit(){AOS.init();} in  app.coponent.ts Entire markup is
- valid and no closing or opening brackets are missing. Elements which
- are not working are getting "aos-init" class but not "aos-animate"